# Is there a way to refactor this JS code so that I am not repeating myself so much?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm very new to JS and struggling to refactor the following code. It functions as expected and opens and closes modal windows, but it is not particularly dry to say the least...

```
// Open modal windows

document.querySelector('#modal-btn1').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal1').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

document.querySelector('#modal-btn2').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal2').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

document.querySelector('#modal-btn3').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal3').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

document.querySelector('#modal-btn4').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal4').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

// Close modal windows

document.querySelector('.close-box1').addEventListener('click', 
  function () {
    document.querySelector('.modal1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'visible';
  });

document.querySelector('.close-box2').addEventListener('click', 
  function () {
    document.querySelector('.modal2').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'visible';
  });

document.querySelector('.close-box3').addEventListener('click', 
  function () {
    document.querySelector('.modal3').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'visible';
  });

document.querySelector('.close-box4').addEventListener('click', 
  function () {
    document.querySelector('.modal4').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'visible';
  });
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use classes and maybe custom attributes !!

Comment: You could write a function that takes in the modal number (it seems like that's all you'd need) and adds the event listeners.

Comment: Thanks for all the very useful suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily minimize how much you repeat code by writing functions that use variables. This is the beauty of programming!

For example, give all your buttons some sort of descriptor that you can use to uniquely identify which modal they should open, then you can write a single event listener to open the correct one.

Example:

If you have elements and modals like this:

```
<button class='modal-button' data-target-modal='modal-1'>
 Open Modal 1
</button>

<div id='modal-1' class='modal'>
  Hi I am modal 1
</div>
```

Then you can have a single function to power all of them like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  let clickedEl = event.target;

  // do this when we click a modal-button
  if(clickedEl.classList.contains('modal-button')) {

     // get the id of the modal via getAttribute
     let modalId = clickedEl.getAttribute('data-target-modal');

     // now get a reference to the actual modal html element
     let modalEl = document.getElementById(modalId);

     // open it!
     modalEl.classList.add('open');


  }
  else
  if(clickedEl.classList.contains('modal-close-button')) {
     // do something similar here for closing!
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryc8xzan/

Comment: `let` variables are block scoped `{ ... }`, so it cannot be declared above the `if` statement and used inside of its block `if () { ... }`. If it works I don't know why, but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes to create your events and link each click event to its modal using custom attributes

see code sample

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn').forEach(function(item){  
  item.addEventListener('click', 
  function(e) {
    var target = item.getAttribute("data-modal");
    document.querySelector(target).style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });
})
```

```css
.modal {
  display:none;
  background:black;
  width:150px;
  height:50x;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-btn" data-modal="#modal1">open modal 1</button>

<button class="modal-btn" data-modal="#modal2">open modal 2</button>

<button class="modal-btn" data-modal="#modal3">open modal 3</button>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">Modal 1</div>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">Modal 2</div>

<div id="modal3" class="modal">Modal 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ID = "#";
const CLASS = ".";

const addEvent = (idOrClass, name, elementsLength, modalDisplay, bodyOverflow) => {
   for(let i=1; i <= elementLength; i++){
     document.querySelector(`${idOrClass}${name}${i}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
       document.querySelector(`.modal{i}`).style.display = modalDisplay;
       document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = bodyOverflow;
     });
   }
}

addEvent(ID, 'modal-btn', 4, 'block', 'hidden');
addEvent(CLASS, 'close-box', 4, 'none', 'visible');
```

Not the prettiest, but this is what i could think of at the top of my head. Usually you would use a framework like Bootstrap to handle modals for you